# Unix shell script to delete older log files

Tags: shell, unix

Could someone please give me the command to delete log files before today (except today and yesterday) date?

Comment: So, that would _actually_ be "before yesterday's", yes?

Comment: yes, i want to delete log files which is  before yesterday..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` with the `-mtime` option to get a list of files modified more than `N` days ago.

For example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -mtime +2
```

will give you all the `*.txt` files in the current directory older than 48 hours.

You can add `-delete` to actually get rid of them.

Comment: OK - that's the command to *find* the files. I think you should add a `-exec rm {} +` or something like that to actually delete the files.

Comment: @bmk, I put in the `-delete` option, there's no point calling sub-shells unnecessarily, unless the `find` is so ancient it doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +2 -delete
```

Comment: I have zip files under log folder how can i delete those files using the command  "find /path/to/files* -mtime +2 -delete" i tried this command igot "find :invalid predicate `-delete'" and u give the solution for that

Comment: You might have an older version of GNU tools. Try this: 

find . -name "*.zip" -mtime +2 -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm {}

Comment: My GNU version is 4.1.20, I tried the "find . -name "*.zip" -mtime +2 -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm {}"command and i got "xargs: invalid option -- I" error

Comment: Oh you are running old release, this should work: 

find . -name "*.zip" -mtime +2  orint0 | xargs -0  rm
Replace . in "find ." with actual path of zip files